# Install PECL extension (Solr) using Chef

Tags: solr, pear, chef-infra, vagrant, pecl

I am trying to have the SOLR PECL extension install using Chef(-Solo) (via Vagrant). As I'm trying to install it on a Zend Server CE box, I can't use or access the normal php cookbook (AFAIK), so I can't use:

```rb
php_pear 'solr' do
  action :install
end
```

In my server.rb file, I have a block like:

```rb
execute "install solr module" do
 command "printf \"\n\n\n\" | pecl install -n solr"
 command "echo 'extension=solr.so' > /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d/solr.ini"
 not_if "test -f /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/solr.so"
end
```

I have already satisfied all the dependencies and if I run this via the command line in the VM it works - but it never seems to run via Vagrant/Chef provisioning (or does, doesn't throw an error but the extension never seems to be created).

What am I missing here?

- is there a way I can use the `php_pear` LWRP without using the whole recipe? (I tried adding it to a `metadata.rb` file but it doesn't seem to help
- failing that, how can I debug why this command is failing? (I've tried upping the debug output but it doesn't show anything more detailed for this command eg. `VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant provision`

If you need, you can see the whole project here: https://github.com/alackmann/vagrant-zend-server/tree/master/vagrant

I also found this which is a similar issue, but wasn't able to work out how to apply it to my situation: https://serverfault.com/questions/363072/how-to-use-only-chefs-php-pear-provider-from-php-cookbook

Comment: I wonder if the `execute` resource is able to contain two `command`s, maybe try with two `execute`s and see if it helps

Comment: add `-vvvv` to the pecl command. it will tell you what happens.